# element not hidden in a keyup event on mobile

Tags: android, jquery, css

I have a `keyup` event which gets the value from an input and checks it against a list of items. The items that do not match, will be hidden.

```
$(".search-cust").on('keyup',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

  if( value.length == 0 ) {
    $('#station-list li').each(function() {
      $(this).show();
    });
    return false;
  }

  $('#station-list li').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).find('.name').text().toLowerCase();
    var comp = $(this).find('.company').text().toLowerCase();
    var mobi = $(this).find('.mobile').text().toLowerCase();
    var cust = $(this).find('.customernumber').text().toLowerCase();

    if(name.match( value )) {
      $(this).show();
    } else if(mobi.match( value )) {
      $(this).show();
    } else if(cust.match( value )) {
      $(this).show();
    } else if(comp.match(value)) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

This works perfectly on desktop but on mobile (in my testcase Samsung Galaxy S2), the element is not being hidden. The event itself works and I did some alerts and saw that it reaches the `else` statement but is not hiding the element.

**Update:** I discovered that when I tilt my phone, the element is gone. So it seems like that the event gets fired and the element gets hidden, but doesn't show on the screen. After tilting (going from vertical view to horizontal and *vice versa*) the phone, the screen updates I think and the element is gone.

Comment: try jquery mobile.or use touchup

Comment: @MHP I updated my question. Maybe that would help troubleshoot the problem.